# CKEditor Custom styles vs Scayt Spell Checker

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I have a custom CMS using CKEditor, Scayt and custom styles.

As a user, if I add a custom style CK adds a span tag and I style for that.
But Scayt also adds a span tag and so my style gets added there too.

I've spent a few hours looking through the code and google for advice but not found anything, although I feel it should be quite simple to fix.

[image]

The problem is that I don't want the spelling errors to use the custom style, the text for them should remain black. I wanted to do this by adding a class to the span that is added to the custom text and then change the CSS for the custom text to work off the class rather than the tag, but I couldn't figure out a neat way to do it.

It does seem to be two common areas of functionality clashing though and so I assume other people have this working somehow without breaking open the code?

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: And the generated HTML code would be useful :-)